Navbar Animated Text Logo on scroll moving menu items
Here is a .gif of what I am doing:

As you can see when the logo animates it shifts the menu items left and right, I have tried separating them by using navbar-start, navbar-center, and navbar-end to prevent this from happening, but as you can tell, nothing I did is working.
How can the logo stay animated without shifting the menu items left and right?
I am using Tailwind CSS.
Here is the code for the navbar:


document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');
    menu.classList.toggle('active');
});
  .mobile-menu {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  .mobile-links {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .mobile-links:hover {
    color: #fffb00;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .dark .mobile-links {
    color: #dbdbdb;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .dark .mobile-links:hover {
    color: #ffdc16;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .menulinks {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .menulinks:hover {
    color: #fffb00;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .dark .menulinks {
    color: #d4d3d3;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .dark .menulinks:hover {
    color: #ff00d4;
    font-size: 1rem;
<nav class="menux glassmorphism p-4 backdrop-blur-2xl">
      <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center">
        <div class="navbar-start text-3xl font-bold logo-fire" aria-labelledby="Explode Logo"><h4 data-value="EXPLODE">EXPLODE</h4></div>
            <div class="navbar-center">
              <ul class="hidden md:flex md:space-x-6">
                <li><a href="#" class="text-center transition menulinks" aria-labelledby="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-center transition menulinks" aria-labelledby="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-center transition menulinks" aria-labelledby="Services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-center transition menulinks" aria-labelledby="Contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="navbar-end">
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <label aria-label="Dark Mode Toggle" class="toggle-switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="darkModeToggle">
                  <span class="toggle-slider">
                    <span class="toggle-icons">
                      <span class="sun-icon">☀️</span>
                      <span class="moon-icon"></span>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </label>
                <button id="menu-toggle" class="md:hidden mm-icon ml-4">
                  <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16m-7 6h7"></path>
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
          <div class="mobile-menu md:hidden mt-4">
            <ul class="space-y-2">
              <li><a href="#" class="block py-2 text-center transition mobile-links" aria-labelledby="Home"> Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="block py-2 text-center transition mobile-links" aria-labelledby="About"> About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="block py-2 text-center transition mobile-links" aria-labelledby="Services"> Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="block py-2 text-center transition mobile-links" aria-labelledby="Contact"> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>




You seem to have forgotten to include the code that animates the "Explode" logo. Also, some classes have been used in the HTML that don't correlate to Tailwind CSS classes. Is there any other relevant CSS code that you also omitted?

I didn't include them because it has nothing to do with the problem.

Try setting a fixed width to the logo container that has aria-labelledby="Explode Logo". If no fixed width it takes a dynamic width as auto which may cause the other elements beside it to adjust their widths to fit the entire navbar, thereby causing shifts in layout.

It would be helpful to provide more CSS that trigger the animations and target the logo container


I am going to give that a try right now. Yep, that did it. Thank you, I guess I was to involved and couldn't think straight.
